# Different react routing result between local and firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-router, firebase-hosting

When i finished my basic routing structure and tested it on Localhost, everything worked fine.

Mycode:

```
const Routes = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/groups" component={AllGroups} />
        <Route exact path="/discussion" component={Discussion} />
        <Route exact path="/group" component={Group} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

However, when i deployed it on Firebase, everything become a whole mass:

For example, i got this page on http://localhost:3000/search.

[image]

But got this on Firebase(Home component).

[image]

The others, groups, group is OK, but discussion, profile, search also show the Home component.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the Firebase takes some time to compile, just like Heroku.

This morning i inputted '/search' again and could get a correct result.

[image]